# T-SQL - Use of sp_xml_preparedocumet in functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, user-defined-functions

i have a problem with functions (UDF) and system procedures.
I can't use a procedures in a UDF.
But is there a workaround for this problem?

I have a view and in the view a will call the function xmlHistory.

In the function i will prepare my XML and then i will return the result.
But i can't run the function due to due to EXEC sp_xml_preparedocumet.

Is there a other solution to use the procedure sp_xml_preparedocumet?

```
SELECT 
        irsys.referencenumber AS [Ticket-Nr], 
        dbo.xmlHistory(irsys.caseid,1,'AssignedRole') AS [Role] ...



CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[xmlHistory] (@caseID int, @historyID int, @name varChar(50) )
RETURNS varChar

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @val varChar(50)
    DECLARE @docHandle int
    DECLARE @xmlDocument nvarchar(max) -- or xml type
        SET @xmlDocument = (SELECT [historyitem]
          FROM [HLDATA].[dbo].[hlsyscasehistory]
          where caseid = @caseID and historyid = @historyID)
        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDocument
        -- Use OPENXML to provide rowset consisting of customer data.

        set @val = (SELECT Value 
        FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, 'HistoryDataDto/ODEs/ODE/Attributes/Attribute',2) 

        WITH (Name varchar(50), Value varchar(50))

        where name = @name)
     RETURN @val
END

GO
```

Thank you

Felix

Comment: Why are you not using the more "native" XML functions, such as [`query()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) or [`value()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)?

Comment: When i use query() or value() i don't can use [OPENXML](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186918.aspx) and so i don't get a table resultset

Comment: Well then, [`nodes()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) sounds like what you want, but given that you then perform assignment to a scalar variable, you've actually got a problem if either of these actually return more than one row.